# C#.NET DataSetRow[] orderBy Parameter

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, dataset

I got a DataSetRow[] which is ordered by the wrong parameter. I get it by using a StoredProcedure, where I told to order by my order-parameter.

There are the first_ID, second_ID, and the order parameter. The first_ID and the second_ID are together the key. The first_ID is always the same. It is ordered by the second_ID. How can I say that it should be ordered by the order-parameter?

```
   DataSet_Edit.StoredProcedureRow[] VAVerweisRow = (DataSet_Edit.StoredProcedureRow[])(ownTableAdapter.GetData(iVAV_ID, "en").Select());
   VAVerweisRow.OrderBy(r => r.order); //can't get use of the return
```

That's how VAVerweisRow looks
**first_ID, sec_ID, order 

'10116', '68627', '2',

'10116', '68638', '1',

'10116', '69591', '4',

'10116', '69592', '3',**

Comment: Well, the Select-Method can have parameters. (string filterExpresone, string orderby)... I use now ...Select("", "order ASC"); and it works!

Answer (score 0):

The Select-Method have a filter and orderby parameter. The new code I use.

```
DataSet_Edit.StoredProcedureRow[] VAVerweisRow = (DataSet_Edit.StoredProcedureRow[])(ownTableAdapter.GetData(iVAV_ID, "en").Select("", "order ASC"));
```